# How to create java.lang.Class with type parameter that is also typed?

Tags: java, generics

What to put on place of ??? in the following code so it would work?

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Generic {

    private static class Foo<T> {
        Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
            assert clazz != null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<List<String>> x = ???;
        Foo<List<String>> t = new Foo<List<String>>(x);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<List<String>> klass = (Class<List<String>>)((Class<?>) List.class);
```

And you do not need an instance of a the class for this type of cast.

Comment: Naah! The problem is type erasure. I hate it! Maybe they fix it some day. And I agree, its ugly as hell :-)

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, all `List` "classes" are equal as the generic type is erased

```
Class<List<String>> x = (Class<List<String>>) (Class) List.class;
```

Comment: It does not compile :( RHS is only Class of List

Comment: That compiles. IDE only complains about unchecked cast, what is perfectly normal.

Comment: I think it does not compile because List.class returns a Class<List>, and that cannot be safely cast to a Class<List<String>>.

Comment: Hmmm, it parsed ok in my IDE. :(

Comment: Now that you edited the answer, it does compile. But it's too late, there is an accepted answer already.